# How to find out SQL Server options updated

Tags: sql-server

Two days ago, we started having problems on a production server executing stored procedures.

No problems on any other servers, only production.

Our investigations found out that the server connection properties `XACT ABORT` were set to `ON`, and this option is `ON` only on the production server.

Now we want to understand when, and possibly who, changed this option. We are looking at the system tables but till now without any luck.

Is there someone who knows if there is a way?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: What kind of "problems" do you have? Performance?

Comment: Sorry for my error. I move by myself to the right place.

Answer (score 1):

1/ First, have a look at these values (make a copy of them for the future):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.configurations
```

A solution is presented [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2364/capturing-and-alerting-on-sql-server-configuration-changes/).

2/ Have you tried to look in Event Viewer?

3/ Have you tried to look in SQL Server logs?

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see a modification date in sys.configurations :-(

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to you mean changes to the `user options` bitmask configuration value (XACT_ABORT ON is 16384). This information is logged to the SQL Server error log with additional information in the default trace, which may be correlated by date and time. Both these are rollover files so the information will be available only for recent changes.

The T-SQL queries below can be run by a sysadmin role member to get this information.

```
--get time of config change and before/after values from error log files
EXEC sp_readerrorlog 1,1,'configuration option';
EXEC sp_readerrorlog 2,1,'configuration option';
EXEC sp_readerrorlog 3,1,'configuration option';
EXEC sp_readerrorlog 4,1,'configuration option';
EXEC sp_readerrorlog 5,1,'configuration option';

--get more infromation (e.g. who made the change) from default trace
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(path), CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(path)) , 255)) + 'log.trc'
    FROM sys.traces
    WHERE
        is_default = 1
    ) AS trace(path)
CROSS APPLY sys.fn_trace_gettable(trace.path, DEFAULT) AS trace_table
JOIN sys.trace_events AS te ON
    te.trace_event_id = trace_table.EventClass
WHERE te.name = 'errorlog'
ORDER BY trace_table.StartTime;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very useful. Yesterday we restarted the server in order to resolve the problem, so now there is no way to see who changed the server options. But I keep in mind those indications.

Comment: @MoS, a new error log is created after restart but the older ones that haven't rolled off might still be available. Same with the default trace files but those also have a max size so the info might roll off sooner depending on activity.

Comment: Thanks Dan, but the older log only show the event and the spid. The log type is Sql Server and I can't see a way to resolve who was logged :-(

Comment: The default trace rollover properties are a max of 5 files of 20MB each. Unfortunately, the trace records of interest probably rolled off due to the amount of traced activity since the change was made.

Answer (score 1):

> Now we want to understand when, and possibly who, changed this option.

System configuration changes are reflected in SQL Server error log. So "when" can be found there:

```
exec xp_readerrorlog 0,1,N'Configuration option' -- change 1st parameter to search in previous logs
```

You'll get back datetime + spid along with the description of the option changed.

You can try to find "who" in SQL server default trace, but it's recycled even more often:

```
select tr.LoginName,
       tr.StartTime,
       tr.TextData
from sys.traces st 
     cross apply (select left(st.[path], len(st.[path]) - nullif(charindex('\', reverse(st.[path])), 0) + 1) + 'log.trc') t(p) 
     cross apply sys.fn_trace_gettable(t.p, default) tr 
where st.is_default = 1 and TextData like '%configur%'
```

Comment: Thanks. Great solution.